# Stack size errors on fine tunning t5 with xsum using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, summarization

I am trying to fine fine tunning t5-small with xsum dataset on pytorch Windows 10 (CUDA 12.1).

Unfortunately **Trainer** (or Seq2SeqTrainer) class from bitsandbytes is not avaliable for Windows, so it was necessary to create a epoch loop:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, get_scheduler
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.optim import AdamW
import torch
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

dataset = load_dataset("xsum")
MODEL_NAME = "t5-small"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

prefix = "summarize: "
max_input_length = 1024
max_target_length = 128

def tokenize_function(examples):
    
    inputs = [prefix + doc for doc in examples["document"]]
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, max_length=max_input_length, truncation=True)

    # Setup the tokenizer for targets
    labels = tokenizer(text_target=examples["summary"], max_length=max_target_length, truncation=True)

    model_inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
    return model_inputs


tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns(['document', 'summary', 'id'])
tokenized_datasets.set_format("torch")

small_train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))
small_eval_dataset = tokenized_datasets["test"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))

train_dataloader = DataLoader(small_train_dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=8)
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(small_eval_dataset, batch_size=8)

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)

num_epochs = 3
num_training_steps = num_epochs * len(train_dataloader)
lr_scheduler = get_scheduler(
    name="linear", optimizer=optimizer, num_warmup_steps=0, num_training_steps=num_training_steps
)

device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
model.to(device)

progress_bar = tqdm(range(num_training_steps))

model.train()

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
        outputs = model(**batch)
        loss = outputs.loss
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        lr_scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        progress_bar.update(1)

model.save_pretrained("outputs/trained")
```

I got this error:

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [352] at entry 0 and [930] at entry 1
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"equal size"?

In your `tokenize_function`, you are truncating the input to a maximum length (`max_input_length`) and the target to a different maximum length (`max_target_length`). A common practice to handle text data of varying lengths is to pad the sequences to a consistent length within each batch. Check if you can pass to tokenizer a [`padding` argument/token](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/pad_truncation) set to `True` or `'longest'` to pad the sequences within a batch to the same length.

```py
def tokenize_function(examples):
    inputs = [prefix + doc for doc in examples["document"]]
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, max_length=max_input_length, truncation=True, padding='longest')

    # Setup the tokenizer for targets
    labels = tokenizer(text_target=examples["summary"], max_length=max_target_length, truncation=True, padding='longest')

    model_inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
    return model_inputs
```

Additionally, make sure the [DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) is properly handling the batches. In some cases, you might need to define a custom collate function (as in [this thread](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-use-huggingface-hf-trainer-train-with-custom-collate-function/50347/3)) to make sure the batches are being formed properly, especially when dealing with text data of varying lengths.

---

If the issue persists, there might be an inconsistency in tensor sizes when the model tries to process the batches.

A possible solution would be to try and  create a custom collate function which makes sure all tensors within a batch are padded to the same length before being fed to the model. In the custom collate function, you can use the tokenizer's `padding` functionality to pad all sequences in a batch to the length of the longest sequence.

```py
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
from torch import nn

def custom_collate_fn(batch):
    inputs = [item['input_ids'] for item in batch]
    labels = [item['labels'] for item in batch]
    
    # Pad sequences within the batch
    padded_inputs = pad_sequence([seq.clone().detach() for seq in inputs], batch_first=True, padding_value=tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    padded_labels = pad_sequence([seq.clone().detach() for seq in labels], batch_first=True, padding_value=tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    
    # Create a new batch with padded sequences
    new_batch = {
        'input_ids': padded_inputs,
        'labels': padded_labels,
        'attention_mask': padded_inputs.ne(tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    }
    return new_batch

# rest of your code

# Use the custom collate function in your DataLoaders
train_dataloader = DataLoader(small_train_dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=8, collate_fn=custom_collate_fn)
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(small_eval_dataset, batch_size=8, collate_fn=custom_collate_fn)

# rest of your code
```

In this custom collate function `custom_collate_fn`, the [`pad_sequence` function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence.html) from PyTorch is used to pad the `input_ids` and `labels` tensors to the length of the longest sequence in the batch. The [`attention_mask`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/glossary#attention-mask) is updated accordingly to indicate where the actual tokens are and where the padding tokens are. That custom collate function is then passed to the `collate_fn` argument of your `DataLoader` instances: that should make all tensors within a batch are padded to the same length before being fed to the model.

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work: RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [79] at entry 0 and [104] at entry 1 (code: https://pastebin.com/DnjHiF19)

Comment: @celsowm OK. Then a custom collate might help. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: warning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).

Comment: @celsowm True: `torch.tensor(sourceTensor)` creates a new tensor with a copy of the data, which can be inefficient, whereas `sourceTensor.clone().detach()` creates a new tensor with the same data but detached from the computation graph, which can be more efficient. I have updated the code accordingly.